# Is there a way to check if an array will exceed the width of a table row?

Tags: javascript

Say I have a table where a row has a defined width.
Example:

```
th:nth-child(1) {
  width: 40%;
}
```

I then add some data into that row, like an array:

```
const fruits = [ banana, strawberry, lemon, orange, grapefruit ]
```

Now I want to check if the fruits array will exceed the width of 40%. If so, I need it to only display the first item in fruits. I know how to do the last part, but I can't figure out how you check whether or not the lenght of the array will exceed the width of the row.

Answer (score 0):

One idea, is make the TH position `relative`, and the add a `div` to this with position `absolute` & `inset` of 0, and `overflow-x` auto.

This trick here is add the text to the div, if the `scrollWidth` is not equal to the `clientWidth` that means a scrollbar was used, with this info you can then decide what to render.

eg.

```js
const fruits = ["banana", "strawberry", "lemon", "orange", "grapefruit", 'apple' ];

const tr = document.querySelector('tr');
tr.remove();
const thead = document.querySelector('thead');


const boxes = [];
for (let l = 0; l < fruits.length; l++) {
  const ntr = tr.cloneNode(true);
  thead.appendChild(ntr);
  boxes.push(ntr.querySelector('th').
    querySelector('div'));
}

function fillBoxes() {
  for (let l = 0; l < fruits.length; l ++) {
    const b = boxes[l];
    b.textContent = fruits.slice(0, l+1).join(', ')
    if (b.clientWidth !== b.scrollWidth) 
      b.textContent = fruits[0];
  }
}


fillBoxes();
window.addEventListener('resize', fillBoxes);
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

th:nth-child(1) {
  width: 40%;
}

th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

th .inner {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><div class="inner"></div></th>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```